# Laplace Transform & Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$ y'' + 4y = \begin{cases} t, & 0 \leq t < 3\\
 1, & 3 \leq t <\infty \end{cases} $$
$$y(0)=0, y'(0)=0$$

I need to find the Laplace transform of the solution of the given IVP above.

I don't know how to take Laplace transform of that kind of piecewise continuous function, need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of Laplace transform is: $$F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(s) e^{-st}\, dt$$

Substitute the function and because integral is linear operation, it can be split into two integrals:

$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty \left(\begin{cases} t, & 0 \leq t < 3\\
 1, & 3 \leq t <\infty \end{cases} \right)e^{-st}\, dt = \int_0^3 t e^{-st}\, dt+\int_3^\infty e^{-st}\, dt $

Comment: But then F(s) = y''(t) + 4y , question asks the Laplace transform of the solution of the IVP. I don't think they are same thing, am I wrong?

Comment: This is just the laplace transform of the piecewise continuous function. You need of course take laplace transform of the other side too and solve for Y(s).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I was thinking about more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a piecewise function using the Heaviside Unit Step Function and then take the Laplace Transform of that.

In your example, we have:

$$\tag 1 f(t) = t - (t - 1)u(t-3)$$

The Laplace Transform of $(1)$ is given by:

$$\mathscr{L} (t - (t - 1)u(t-3)) = \dfrac{1}{s^2} + \dfrac{e^{-3s}}{s} -\dfrac{e^{-3s}(3s +1)}{s^2}$$

- $\mathscr{L} (y''(t)) = s^2y(s) -s y(0) -y'(0) = s^2y(s)$
- $\mathscr{L} (4y'(t)) = 4(sy(s) -y(0)) = 4s y(s)$

Can you know finish it off?

Comment: I don't know about the Heaviside Unit Step Function yet, but your answer is really useful. Thanks!

Comment: Two upvotes for answers: yours and for B.S.+1

Answer (score 2):

Another approach may be given by:

> If $\mathfrak{U}_c(x)= \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             0 & 0\leq x \leq c \\
>             x & \quad x > c
>         \end{array}
>     \right.~~$ where $c>0$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) then:
>
> $$
> f(x) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             f_1(x) & \quad 0\leq x<a \\
>            f_2(x) & \quad x \ge a
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$ can be written as $f(x)=f_1(x)-f_1(x)\mathfrak{U}_a(x)+f_2(x)\mathfrak{U}_a(x)$.

Apply this useful hint for your function on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $ Y(s):=  \int_0^\infty y(t) e^{-st}\, dt$,

and we have $t[u(t)-u(t-3)]+u(t-3)=\begin{cases} t, & 0 \leq t < 3\\
 1, & 3 \leq t <\infty \end{cases}$

Then, apply Laplace to both sides.